# How to move legacy git repository to Gitlab that require GPG sign?

Tags: git, gnupg, repository, gitlab

Currently the company I am working for has a legacy git repository that host elsewhere and all commits are not GPG signed. The project is getting bigger and more people are working for the same project, so it is moved to Gitlab and will now need to have all commit GPG signed.

The problem is that the legacy project got some commits that are done by former employee. After they left the company, even the company email they used in the commit is gone. There is no way to have the correct GPG sign apply to those commit. One easy solution would be copy the current code to a new folder and make a new initial commit. However, if I don't want to throw away the previous commit history, is there a way I can GPG sign those commit that is not done by me? (Or is there other solution? I am not the admin, but I may ask the admin to make the changes if the instruction is clear)

Comment: Does Gitlab actually enforce that the signer's email matches the committer's email?

Comment: (Honestly my preferred method would be to just ask the admins to give an exemption, since signing old commits involves a rewrite...)

Comment: @user1686 Is it possible to give exemption to previous commit only? As for new commit, GPG sign would be necessary for security reason.

Comment: Turn GPG singing off, import the old repo, turn GPG singing on?

Comment: @user1686 It cannot be turned on again as there are previous commit that is not GPG signed.

Comment: Have you checked that it can't be turned on again?  GitHub's feature doesn't work that way, and I'm pretty sure GitLab's also only applies to new commits.